# What is regional homogeneity in neurology?

Tags: terminology, neurology, imaging

newbie to.neurology here. For context, I'm studying this article (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-89166-8#Sec14) which relates the gut microbiome to brain structure in schizophrenia patients. The paper uses the term "regional homogeneity" so often throughout the paper without explaining what it means, and my attempts to research it only leave me more confused. I only understand it as some measure of
brain activity with other stuff related to synchronization. That's kind of a problem since so much of my project depends on knowing what it means exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 4th paragraph of the introduction (*Alterations in brain function...*) and the 4th paragraph of the method section titled "MRI data collection and preprocessing" (*The ReHo index was calculated...*) tell you what it means. You probably need to read the cited references for a deeper understanding, or at least search Kendall's coefficient of concordance.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Then one needs an explanation of voxel and connectome, not regional homogeneity. Regional homogeneity similarly can be simply understood from the separate meanings of those two words, but what's relevant for this paper is how it's calculated which is very clear in the methods.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike: Thank you for pointing me in a general direction, but I can't afford to go down the rabbit hole of researching and understanding what functional connectivity and friends mean. Do you understand this concept at all, and if so, would you be willing to walk me through it?

Comment: @Specs_Goldfish Hi, I'm sorry, but, your comment is not correct. In fact, you can't afford *not* to go down that rabbit hole if you want to use this technique for anything at all. Your project *depends* on you going down that rabbit hole, and really, understanding functional connectivity at least at a level sufficient to understand this technique is not a "rabbit hole", it's one of the principal methods used to study human neurobiology. Ignoring it would be like leaving telescopes out of astronomy.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike: You're right, I absolutely need to read everything to get a formal understanding, but for a dense high school student with a presentation due in two days, any sort of oversimplified explanation will do. I apologize for showing up so unprofessionally.

Comment: @Specs_Goldfish I'd start with at least the Wikipedia article on resting state fMRI. You might also search "functional connectivity" here or on Psych & Neuro StackExchange. Taking shortcuts due to a short deadline is a strategy you should quickly learn to avoid - one strategy is to be better prepared further in advance of the deadline.

Comment: You state, "...my project depends on knowing what it means exactly..." Then you need to know exactly, which can't be explained in a couple of sentences. You're asking professionals to help you out of a jam (a time crunch) that you created for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Good question! The brain is composed of billions of cells, and not all of them are doing the same thing at the same time. Some areas of the brain may be more active than others at any given moment. However, within specific regions, the cells (or neurons) are expected to be working together -- or, in other words, they should be synchronized.

When we use fMRI to scan the brain, we're creating a 3D image, and each tiny cube or box within that 3D image is called a voxel. I.e., "volumetric pixel," just a box instead of a square like a pixel. Each voxel represents a tiny portion of the brain, containing a large number of neurons. In an fMRI scan, the intensity of the signal we receive from each voxel can tell us how active that part of the brain is (based on, for example, how much blood is being used in the region).

ReHo is a measure of how similar the activity is within a cluster of voxels. If they are all behaving very similarly — if they're all increasing or decreasing their activity at the same time — then we say they have high regional homogeneity.

To calculate ReHo, we use Kendall's coefficient of concordance to tell us how well the activity across a cluster of voxels is synchronized.

You can imagine that some disorders would disrupt brain connectivity/communication between neurons, resulting in more disorganization. Or you could imagine that excessively high ReHo might indicate some altered state of mind.

Comment: From my reading, your answer is correct but very simplified. I don't know just how much detail the OP needs (for example, how much volume is in a voxel, and approximately how many neurons in that voxel, how many voxels in a cluster, and how Kendall's coefficient tells us how well activity in a cluster is synchronized.) But what I *really* don't understand is your last sentence. I think you need to provide some support for it. Thanks.